# How to retrieve every objectClass available with python-ldap?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap, object-class

Given a valid `python-ldap` context, how can I query all the [objectClass](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/python-ldap-3.3.0/reference/ldap-schema.html#ldap.schema.models.ObjectClass) available in the LDAP server? I suppose the result would be a list of `ldap.schema.models.ObjectClass`.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026546/get-all-possible-attributes-and-all-objectclasses-from-openldap-in-php answers this question, although the code example is PHP rather than Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it with:

```
import ldap

l = ldap.initialize(ldap_uri)
l.simple_bind_s(ldap_bind_dn, ldap_bind_pw)
res = l.search_s("cn=subschema", ldap.SCOPE_BASE, "(objectclass=*)", ["*", "+"])
subschema_entry = res[0]
subschema_subentry = ldap.cidict.cidict(subschema_entry[1])
subschema = ldap.schema.SubSchema(subschema_subentry)
object_class_oids = subschema.listall(ldap.schema.models.ObjectClass)
object_classes = [
    subschema.get_obj(ldap.schema.models.ObjectClass, oid) for oid in object_class_oids
]
```